How to close connections for query tools when close pgAdmin4 in browser without closing query tools?
Sometimes users close pgAdmin4 browser tab without closing query tools.
In this case all connections for query tools are still reamining, they are alive.
For example, open two query tools in pgAdmin4, check number of connections.
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity
It says there are 20 active connections.
Close pgAdmin4 in browser without closing query tools, open pgAdmin4 again and open another query tool.
There are 21 active connections including two connections for previous opened query tools which are closed with pgAdmin4.
When close pgAdmin4, all connections to query tools should be closed.

What version of pgadmin4 are you running?  What OS are you running it on? Are you in desktop mode or server mode?

I'm using pgAdmin4 8.5, Google Chrome, Windows 11
